# Double integration that is not on google

Tags: calculus

I came across some equation in physics which had a different kind of integration. Like it should have $dx2$ but had $d2x$ . And I did some substitution for solving it like putting $x= u^2$ and then double differentiating it to get $d2x = 2.du2$ . So I thought it could be right but my teachers said we can not do this and no other proof is coming into my mind.!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Bg8.jpg)

Comment: Is $d^2x$ shorthand for $dx dx$? This seems poor notation. The obvious thing to try seems to me to integrate wrt x twice to obtain $1/6x^3+cx+d$, but maybe something else is meant.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Dx2 means dx.dx

Comment: So how can we double integrate a function (d2x) and not (dx2)

Comment: To all whose who think that this is poor notation: How else are you supposed to integrate over arbitrarily many variables? See user66081's answer: The function might as well be another arbitrary function $f$ of $\mathbf{x}$, not just $\mathbf{x}$ itself. (i.e. $f=f(\mathbf{x})=f(x,y)$)

Comment: @acarturk, I had no idea this could be a vector, I always use an arrow in my notes. If it's a vector then of course this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I guess we are dealing here with $\int \int \mathbb{x} \, d^2 \mathbb{x}$, where $\mathbb{x}$ is a vector. Another notation for this would be
$$
\int \int \left( x \atop y \right) dx dy
.
$$

This quantity is related to the [center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass).

The wiki page on [multiple integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral) mentions that notation in the section "Mathematical definition".

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an abuse of the notation for the infinitesimal $dx$. Often scientists (most frequently Physicists) will use slightly misleading notation due to a few little "calculus tricks" which are not 100% mathematically sound but work 90% of the time.

In this case, I believe it is written like this because of the form of the second differential operator,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{d}{dx}\right)(u)=\frac{d}{dx}\left ( \frac{du}{dx} \right ) = \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(u).$$

Often when people are taught how to solve a separable ordinary differential equation like,

$$\frac{du}{dx}=f(u)g(x),$$

they are taught to "put all the $x$ on one side and put all the $u$ on the other",

$$\frac{1}{f(u)}\frac{du}{dx}=g(x).$$

The next step is the one which is often taught in a "misleading" way, some students are told to "multiply by $dx$" to give

$$\frac{1}{f(u)}du = g(x)dx,$$

"and then integrate" (just stick integral signs in front of both sides of the equation),

$$\int \frac{1}{f(u)}du = \int g(x)dx.$$

Now you might ask, the result is correct so why does it matter if this is not 100% mathematically sound? Well it goes back to the simple fact that an integral is an operator with respect to some basis. Therefore one cannot simply "stick integral signs in front of both sides".

Instead, if we were to integrate both sides we **must** integrate with respect to some variable and we **must not** break the sacred equality rule - perform the identical operations on the left hand side as you do the right - i.e. we integrate both sides with respect to the same variable.

So instead of "multiplying by $du$", what actually is going on is that from 
$$\frac{1}{f(u)}\frac{du}{dx}=g(x),$$
we **integrate both sides with respect to $x$**, producing

$$\int \frac{1}{f(u)}\frac{du}{dx}dx=\int g(x)dx,$$

as required.

In summary, it is abuses like this which lead to misleading notation such as $d^2x$ rather than $(dx)^2$ or more acceptably $dx dx$.